# Odd issue with multiple instances of an app that uses WebView2 and the same user data folder

Tags: webview, com

I have a classic Windows desktop application and we have added WebView2 to it to host some web pages in the app. Now we have an odd issue if a user is running multiple instances of our application.

When a user opens a document in one instance, the user is unable to work with the other instance while the document is loading. I have found that the other instance of the application is not getting any messages during the load.

We are not doing anything with the WebView2 in either application when loading our storage as the WV2 instance is created on app startup. This issue happens whenever we open a file in either instance - the other one quits responding.

When I run spyxx I see no messages during the open process. Our call to GetMessage simply waits until the load is complete. We are compound document/storage application and a COM application that uses MFC. We use the COM interfaces in WebView2 in our c++ code.

I have found that when we create the WV2, as long as I use a different user data folder, and hence underlying WV process for each instance of our app, the issue goes away. We are getting message as expected in the other instance.

I am trying to determine why there are no messages going to an instance of our app when we use the same user data folder. I have eliminated a number of other potential causes. I stopped putting our OLE message filter in the busy state. I quit registering our document during open with the running object table. I quit registering our app active object. I quit calling LockWindowUpdate for our frame. I quit setting the busy cursor (yes getting desperate here). So far nothing I do works other than creating each app's WV2 with a different user folder.

Anyone have an ideal of how sharing the user data folder can cause messages to stop being sent to another instance of our app?

Comment: Do you have a reproducible project? Testing with official samples (https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Samples/tree/main/SampleApps) and multiple processes using the same user data folder doesn't seem to exhibit any problem like the one you mention [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Not exactly. I have one giant desktop app. But, I can get Microsoft support the app and a temp license.

Comment: You could download the viewer version of the app. Search for Solid Edge Free viewer. I could send you a large file that takes a bit of time to open. https://resources.sw.siemens.com/en-US/download-solid-edge-free-viewer

Comment: Not sure I understand, this is not a reproducing *code* project.